# fuser command in centos print an unwanted output in bash script

Tags: bash, centos7, pid, fuser

I'm using centOS 7, and I'm trying to check what is the pid of a process using port X/tcp with "fuser" command, through a bash script, like so:

```
  some_pid=$(fuser X/tcp) > /dev/null
  another_pid=$(fuser Y/tcp) > /dev/null
  ...
  if [[ -z "$some_pid" ]]; then ...
```

Although I don't want anything to be printed to the console, the results are:

```
X/tcp:
Y/tcp:
...
```

When I try to run fuser with -s, then the if statment returns false, because the result of the fuser is empty, for some reason.

How can I avoid the unwanted printing?
Why when I run fuser in silent mode it returns empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `fuser` man page you can see

> fuser outputs only the PIDs to stdout, everything else is sent to stderr.

That is you need to get rid of the `stderr` output.

```
some_pid=$( fuser X/tcp 2> /dev/null )
```